# I got this error 'DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or categorical' - xgboost XGBRFRegressor

Tags: python, python-3.x, xgboost

I'm going to train this as an xgboost model (XGBRFRegressor).

[image]

But this kind of error occurred and I've never seen like this before.

```
ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float, bool or category.  When
categorical type is supplied, DMatrix parameter `enable_categorical` must
be set to `True`. Invalid columns:
```

code:

```
from xgboost import XGBRFRegressor
# creating object of XGBoost
model_xgb = XGBRFRegressor(max_depth=8, n_estimators = 10)
# Training model
model_xgb.fit(X_train, y_train)
# Predicting values
pred_xgb = model_xgb.predict(X_test)
# Evaluation metrics "Mean Squared Error"
mae_xgb = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(y_test, pred_xgb))
print(mae_xgb)
```

how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

transform the field you got to int, then checks if the failure which column is relating to that field.

transform it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).